# Corrupted linked list

Tags: math

Suppose you are given a pointer to the head of a singly linked list. Normally each node in the list has a pointer to the next element, and the last node's pointer is Null. Unfortunately the list might have been corrupted so that some node's pointer leads back to an earlier node in the list.

How can I design an algorithm to detect whether the linked list is corrupted or not keeping in mind that run time is O(n).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The Q&A format may suggest otherwise, but this site is for programming contest. Unless you're willing to shape your question into a contest with an objective winning criterion, this is not the site for you.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Algorithms

Comment: please guide me what is the correct forum...i am a novice...

Comment: @Konad23 stackoverflow